# Extract a substring from a text file using a positional argument

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed, grep

I extract the specific line with `awk 'FNR == 6 {print $1}' infile.txt`. Suppose this line is `QWKEJQKSKMAOJISDKJFSDWESA`. What should I pipe with `awk` in order to extract the characters in between the 10th and 15th positions of this string?

Comment: `perl -anE '$.==6 && say substr $F[0],10,5' infile.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print substr($1,10,6)
```

check the math depending what "between" means to you.

Comment: Thanks. I was too focused on the `sed` and `grep` and didn't know `awk` had a `substr` function. Sorry about the newbie question.